# Spring Connectivity with Postgres DB

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc

Trying to connect to Postgres DB, context params are as below:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
<property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/****" />
<property name="username" value="****" />
<property name="password" value="****" />
</bean>
```

Getting exception on context loading:

> SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml]: Error setting property
>   values; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested
>   PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are: PropertyAccessException 1:
>   org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property
>   'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class
>   [org.postgresql.Driver]

I have the postgres driver in the LIB of the project, as I can check the class file org.postgresql.Driver. The Class.forName also gives a positive result for the driver class.
I have tried all versions of postgres drivers, but still this isn't going through.

Comment: are you using maven / gradle? can you post your pom / build file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue , When I added the Postgres DB Jar to the WEBINF/Lib the bean was getting created , Some how it was not picking the jar from the JavaResource/Lib as i was doing this before .

The problem is a particular case which is not answered in most of the places well and just checking the classpath wont be a correct answer to this query.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the lib gets copied to the packaging correctly and that that directory is in the classpath.

Comment: Thats all been checked , I have it with other libs , I am using Spring lib and commons lib along with this , Directory is in classpath . The check for this is i used Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver") which proved driver being there in classpath. Any other Clue , or check i can do ?